# Network call from Android widgets

Tags: android

How it is possible to do a network call from a widget in Android?
I have a widget which will show the result from an API call from a webservice.
So how it is possible to call the HttpGet method in a widget?

Answer (score 4):

> So how it is possible to call the Httpget method in a widget?

An `AppWidgetProvider` is a subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`, and methods like `onUpdate()` are called from the receiver's `onReceive()`. It is not safe for you to do HTTP I/O here, as you are on the main application thread, and this work may take too long, freezing your UI and possibly causing an ANR dialog.

Instead, delegate the HTTP work to an `IntentService` you trigger from `onUpdate()`. The `IntentService` can then update the `RemoteViews` of the app widget, if needed.